# How to get to inner Maybe monad to extract class name from html button in purescript?

Tags: html, purescript

I am attempting to learn `purescript`.

I have a button in some HTML that I am trying to print the class name of. I am building and `browserifying` using `pulp`.

The function I am using is querySelector:

```
import Web.DOM.ParentNode (querySelector)
```

This returns the item I want, *Element*, within two "boxes": an outer Effect monad and an embedded Maybe monad:

```
> :type querySelector
QuerySelector -> ParentNode -> Effect (Maybe Element)
```

My Effect monad looks like:

```
getBtn ::  Effect Unit
getBtn = do
  doc <- map toParentNode (window >>= document)
  button <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc
  ... Need to extract class name from 'button' here
```

I know I can get to the inner Maybe by calling bind (>>=) on the outer Effect monad.  My first plan of attack was to unbox the Maybe manually using the *maybe* funtion.  Here's how you do this for a simple Int:

```
> maybe 0 (\x -> x) $  Just 7
7
```

for a *Maybe Element* I think it would look something like:

```
unboxMaybeElement :: Maybe Element -> Element
unboxMaybeElement Nothing = Nothing
unboxMaybeElement (Just a) = maybe (Element ..note: trying to create a default element here) (\x -> x) a
```

One problem is I cannot find a constructor for type *Element*, so I am unable to supply a default value (the first arg of *maybe*), so I can't use this method.

In addition, I can't find a definition for the *Element* type.

I also read that it's not a good idea to reach inside a Maybe anyway, but instead to lift the functions going against it by using a functor (like map or `fmap`).

In this vein I tried to call an external function like:

```
  button <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc
  let cn = getClassName button
  log $ "classname=" <> show cn

-- The basic question is how to implement this function?
getClassName :: Maybe HTMLElement -> String
getClassName e = map className  (map fromElement e)
```

Note: *className* and *fromElement* are supplied in Web.HTML.HTMLElement.

As you can see, I'm trying to promote up the functions by calling them with a map, because the functions do *not* deal with Maybes, but I'm getting stuck in a morass of type conflicts between "Maybe Element" and "Element" and "HTMLElement" vs "Element" etc.

Yes, I admit I have a couple of issues going on here, and this isn't really a beginners problem, but it just irks me that something so simple as obtaining the class name of an HTML object is so hard.  Surely, I must be missing something?

BTW, Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <p>
      <input type="button" class="btn-class" value="click me" id="btn"/>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The more general question is: how do you get to values nested two monad levels deep?

Comment: have you tried `fmap`, to promote a function? `map` operate on lists.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this distinction and did try, but for the life of me I can't find any fmap definition in purescript?  It's certainly not in the prelude, or Data.Functor, or Data.Maybe.  I *do* see a fmap in ghci though.  There are some differences between Haskell and Purescript, and maybe this is one?

Comment: Forgive me, i missed that this was purescrict. You can see here: https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/master/src/Data/Functor.purs That the mapping operation is indeed called `map` in purescript. What is your type signature for `className`? and can you edit your post to include the error you get when you tried to lift the function?

Comment: No clear idea, but two thoughts: 1. `getClassName :: Maybe HTMLElement -> String` looks odd: what string should be returned in case of `Nothing`?
2. Not sure where `fromElement` is coming from, but I guess it returns `Maybe` as well? If so, mapping over a `Maybe` with this function would add another "layer" of `Maybe`. Sounds like you need `>>=` or do-notation.
My general advice would be to add type signatures and use _typed holes_ to see what types the compiler expects. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you did a good job by investigating this problem on your own, I can just suggest refactoring based on the example, that you've provided.

Let's say we don't care about logging failed messages on a particular case. That means, that we can replace every such a logging by `pure unit`:

```
getBtn ::  Effect Unit
getBtn = do
  log "now in getBtn"
  doc <- map toParentNode (window >>= document)
  mbtn <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc
  case mbtn of
    Nothing -> pure unit
    Just btn -> do
      let mhtmlEl = fromElement btn
      case mhtmlEl of
        Nothing -> pure unit
        Just htmlEl -> do
          let cn = className htmlEl
          log $ "classname below:"
          cn >>= log
```

Then we can notice an interesting pattern here:

```
case mbtn of
  Nothing -> pure unit
  Just btn -> do
    let mhtmlEl = fromElement btn
```

i.e we want to apply `fromElement` function on a `btn` value if it `Just btn` or do nothing if it's `Nothing`. The resulting type must be `Maybe` value.

The first thought is using `map` function, but the type of `fromElement` is `fromElement :: Element -> Maybe HTMLElement`, so the resulting type will be `Maybe (Maybe a))`.

Anyway, we can even [search](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=Maybe%20a%20%20-%3E%20%28a%20-%3E%20Maybe%20b%29%20-%3E%20Maybe%20b) such a function by type and the first result is [`bind`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.0/docs/Control.Bind#v:bind) (the same as `(>>=)`). So let's refactor (with pointing the types as comments just for clarity, but sure it's not necessary):

```
getBtn ::  Effect Unit
getBtn = do
  log "now in getBtn"
  doc <- map toParentNode (window >>= document)
  mbtn <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc

  let mhtmlEl = fromElement =<< mbtn -- Maybe HTMLElement

  case mhtmlEl of
    Nothing -> pure unit
    Just htmlEl -> do
      let cn = className htmlEl
      log $ "classname below:"
      cn >>= log
```

The next step is to reduce another `case` expression. Here's using [map](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.0/docs/Data.Functor#v:map) (the same as `<$>`) will be enough:

```
getBtn ::  Effect Unit
getBtn = do
  log "now in getBtn"
  doc <- map toParentNode (window >>= document)
  mbtn <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc

  let mhtmlEl = (fromElement =<< mbtn) -- Maybe HTMLElement
  let mCn = className <$> mhtmlEl -- Maybe (Effect String)

  case mCn of
      Nothing -> log "no such element"
      Just cn -> do
          log $ "classname below:"
          cn >>= log
```

The resulting type of `getBtn` function, must be `Effect Unit`, so every case of `Maybe` value must be processed here. I would leave it like this, since it quite clear, what's going on here. But if you seeking a concise representation, then `maybe` function can be applied here:

```
getBtn ::  Effect Unit
getBtn = do
  log "now in getBtn"
  doc <- map toParentNode (window >>= document)
  mbtn <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc

  let mhtmlEl = (fromElement =<< mbtn) -- Maybe HTMLElement
  let mCn = className <$> mhtmlEl -- Maybe (Effect String)

  maybe (log "no such element") (\cn -> log "classname below:" *> cn >>= log) mCn
```

Comment: Yes, that’s the kind of solution I was striving for and knew had to be there somewhere!  It demonstrates to me how Haskell (PureScript) really is mathematical and functions really  *are* expressions.  I essentially had “y= x + x + x” and you showed it can be written more simply as “y = 3x”, for example.  Interesting how Haskell allows for such objective and almost algorithmic refactorings.  Thanks for the lesson in precision thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some similar code I saw in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQ-BoxFwxTM&t=465s), I was able to get something that compiled.  I'm not saying this is the best way, or even a good way, just that it works:

```
getBtn ::  Effect Unit
getBtn = do
  log "now in getBtn"
  doc <- map toParentNode (window >>= document)
  mbtn <- querySelector (wrap "#btn") doc
  case mbtn of
    Nothing -> log "mbtn failed"
    Just btn -> do
      let mhtmlEl = fromElement btn
      case mhtmlEl of
        Nothing -> log "mhtml failed"
        Just htmlEl -> do
          let cn = className htmlEl
          log $ "classname below:"
          cn >>= log
          pure unit
      pure unit
  pure unit
pure unit
```

The "m" on some variable names ("mbtn", "mhtmlEl") is presumably to denote it's a wrapped object i.e. monadic.  It's important that in your `case Just` statements you specify a different variable than in the `case of` statement, one without an "m" in front ("btn", "htmlEl"), to denote it's a raw or unwrapped value.

the `pure unit` lines are essentially dummy lines to appease the requirement that a monad always returns something other than a "binder" (a let or '<-' assignment), so you may or may not need them depending on how your do workflow is constructed.

There are effectively two levels of `Maybe` in this example: one on the `querySelector` result and one on the `fromElement` result.  Add in another `do` to process the raw `HTMLElement` and you're up to three levels of `do`.

Unfortunately, the `querySelector` appears to be returning `Nothing` for me, but this is an orthogonal issue.  That was the whole motivation for printing the className -- to determine if it was finding the element or not.